# how to release an object which use copy keyword in iOS program

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

In my program, I tried to set object in an dictionary. Values are coming from another class, so I copied those values before processing it.

While analyzing the code I got leaks.

```
-(void)giveInput:(NSString *)userInput ForPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder{

    [inputValue setObject:[userInput copy] forKey:[placeholder copy]];

}
```

How to release the userINput and Placehoder object retain count?

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html), you should `release` or at least `autorelease` any references you got from `alloc`, `new` or `copy`.

In your case, try changing `[userInput copy]` to `[[userInput copy] autorelease]`; likewise for `placeholder`.

EDIT:
Note though, the default `NSDictionary` and `NSMutableDictionary` classes already copy keys and retain values -- see the Memory Management Programming Guide as well as [the NSMutableDictionary class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000141-BABBDAFD) for further details. Hence, there's no need for `[placeholder copy]`, and if you did not mean to create a separate copy of `userInput`, there is no need to `copy` it also.

Comment: While you are correct in saying that `NSMutableDictionary` retains objects that are added to it, this is different from copying. If you want the objects to be immune to external manipulation, they must be copied.

Comment: Very true, I should have added this as a warning to my answer, since we have no idea what is done to the objects added to the dictionary.

Comment: Actually, NSDictionary objects already **copy** keys... (that is, key objects must conform to `NSCopying`).

Comment: Thanks @dreamlax, further edited my answer to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)giveInput:(NSString *)userInput ForPlaceholder:(NSString *)placeholder{
    NSString *cpUserInput = [userInput copy];
    NSString *cpPlaceholder = [placeholder copy];
    [inputValue setObject:cpUserInput forKey:cpPlaceholder];
    [cpUserInput release];
    [cpPlaceholder release];
}
```

Or in a fewer lines with autorelease:

```
[inputValue setObject:[[userInput copy] autorelease] forKey:[[placeholder copy] autorelease]];
```

**when adding objects to dictionaries/arrays they get retained*

Answer (score 0):

When you copy an object, you take ownership of the copy. `setObject:forKey:` retains objects before they are added; this means that you have over-retained `userInput` and `placeholder`: they will never be deallocated. To fix your memory leaks, relinquish ownership of the objects by calling `autorelease`.

```
[inputValue setObject:[[userInput copy] autorelease] forKey:[[placeholder copy] autorelease]];
```

I recommend you read Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).